# OAuth token state and invalidate

Tags: rest, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Given I have acquired an OAuth2 token from [https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token](https://login.windows.net/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/token) using the password grant type, is their a REST API to

1. get the status of that token
2. invalidate the token (logout)

I will be using this token to access Power BI REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

- The access token you acquired from Azure AD actually is a string as a JSON Web Token (JWT) that's base 64 encoded. You can drop that string into a decoder like [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/) lets you see the contents.
- Access tokens cannot be revoked and are valid until their expiry. For more info, please refer to [Configurable token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-types).

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am still fairly new to OAuth. Slightly unrelated - I don't understand how a JWT OAuth token can be secure if it's only Base64 encoded, allowing anyone to decode it and view its content. Surely they should be encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron already mentioned, you acquired a token from Azure AD, which is a JSON Web Token (JWT). These are a de facto standard structure for tokens. You should use https://jwt.io/ decoded to copy-paste your token there and see whole structure.

Within this structure, you will have information like:

- When this token has been created
- Until when this token is valid
- What permissions have been granted to you

Note: I was working on some Azure implementation recently, and I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/:tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token as the endpoint for a token request point.

Moreover, related to your initial question...

I don't see a use case to actually revoke a token, but if you want to simulate situation like this (on logout or something), you could use 'refresh token' endpoint which would invalidate token and create a new one. If you decide NOT TO DELIVER this token to your end user, it will be as you simply revoked it.

So, some good use case would be:

1. User decided to log out
2. You invoke refresh token endpoint for that user
3. You DO NOT deliver a new token to the end user
4. User has the old token and can't use it anymore

If you need a quick tutorial on how to refresh token, you can find it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens

I hope that you'll find this helpful.

Kind regards,